# Can I somehow toggle a Checkbox with a Global Hotkey?

Tags: c#, checkbox, toggle, global

I am fairly new to C# and I started to make little tools for games.

Now I found out that it is a pain in the butt to tab out all the time to toggle the checkbox, set yourself in a special mode, go to the destination, tab out and toggle the checkbox again, so you are in the normal mode again.

I thought it might be easier if you could press NumPad9 to toggle the Checkbox, while you are ingame, or tab out if you want.

I really didn't find something, or I didn't understand the solutions, since I am a beginner in C#.

It would be really cool if you could help me with my problem.

I already enabled KeyPreview in the Form but that's all I know really.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form won't have focus when you press the designated key, you'll likely need to use `GetAsyncKeyState` from the WinAPI to achieve this.

Have a look at the documentation for it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

And use it in C#:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```